# How is it possible to draw

Tags: r, geolocation, ggmap

I have a datset that shows time, latitude and longitude in Beijing, China. How is it possible to draw a line between points based on time (direction move from min(time) to max(time))?

I found a package `ggmap`, however could not get the API from it. Are there any other options to do it?

```
structure(list(time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2008-02-05 07:01:35", 
"2008-02-06 07:02:00", "2008-02-07 07:02:45", "2008-02-08 07:00:37"
), class = "factor"), lon = c(116.36606, 116.36605, 116.36611, 
116.36615), lat = c(39.68409, 39.68409, 39.68408, 39.68413)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `ggplot2::geom_line` and `geom_path` don't care about an API, they'll draw the lines. The difference is that `geom_path` *"connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data"*, which is likely what you want (once you have sorted your data on `time`). So for me, `ggplot(df[order(df$time),], aes(lon, lat)) + geom_path()` seems like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: It isn't clear though if the purpose of this question is how to plot contiguous time-sequenced points, or how to fix a problem with the `ggmap` API from Beijing. Those two are unrelated, I recommend you stick with one question here.